# Is there a way to restyle Xamarin switch or checkbox to look like this?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

I got this mockup design for my app but I have no idea how to implement this. I assume this can be implemented through some custom renderer but couldn't find any solution.

Any hint can be helpful, thanks :)

Comment: Use a segmented control, or build your own custom button that maintains state.  You shouldn’t need a custom renderer

Comment: Or search chips. Or build one with frame and label and change the color accordingly

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of these controls.